# IB API order placement error: cannot set VOL attribute on non-vol order

Tags: go, ib-api

I'm trying to use [a Go port](https://godoc.org/github.com/gofinance/ib) of the ib API to connect to my Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation.

I can connect and read data from the API but when I try to place an order on a paper trading account I get the following error:

```
&{1 321 Error validating request:-'bB' : cause - Cannot set VOL attribute on non-VOL order.}
```

But I do not believe I set a VOL attribute in the request. A minimal program that reproduces the error is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"

    "github.com/gofinance/ib"
)

func main() {
    eng, err := ib.NewEngine(ib.EngineOptions{
        DumpConversation: true,
        Gateway:          "127.0.0.1:1122",
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Connection error: %v", err)
    }
    // Note: you have to make sure the connection has been fully established
    // before attempting to do any requests to the TWS. Failure to do so will
    // result in the TWS closing the connection. Typically this can be done by
    // waiting for a callback from an event and the end of the initial connection
    // handshake, such as IBApi.EWrapper.nextValidId or IBApi.EWrapper.managedAccounts
    // https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/connection.html
    // TODO take apart engine.go and make it wait properly.
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    defer eng.Stop()
    // printInstrument(eng)
    reqID := eng.NextRequestID()
    o := make(chan ib.Reply)
    eng.Subscribe(o, reqID)
    order := ib.Order{
        Action:     "BUY",
        OrderType:  "LMT",
        TotalQty:   100,
        LimitPrice: 95.94,
    }
    contract := ib.Contract{
        SecurityType:    "STK",
        Symbol:          "MSFT",
        Exchange:        "SMART",
        PrimaryExchange: "NASDAQ",
        Currency:        "USD",
    }
    req := &ib.PlaceOrder{
        Order:    order,
        Contract: contract,
    }
    req.SetID(reqID)
    if err := eng.Send(req); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Send error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Waiting for reply...")
    reply := <-o
    fmt.Println(reply)
}
```

And the output from the program is:

```
$ go run main.go
2> '71-1-2-'
2< &{15 1} &{[DU1029297]}
2< &{9 1} &{1}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.us}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ilhmds}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:euhmds}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:fundfarm}
2< &{4 2} &{-1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds}
2> '3-42-1-0-MSFT-STK--0---SMART-NASDAQ-USD-----BUY-100-LMT-95.94-0-----0--0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0--0-------0--0-0---0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0--0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-----0---0-0--0--'
Waiting for reply...
2< &{4 2} &{1 321 Error validating request:-'bB' : cause - Cannot set VOL attribute on...
&{1 321 Error validating request:-'bB' : cause - Cannot set VOL attribute on non-VOL order.}
```

Note especially the dump from the ib engine `3-42-1-0-MSFT-STK--0---SMART-NASDAQ-USD-----BUY-100-LMT-95.94-0-----0--0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0--0-------0--0-0---0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0--0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-----0---0-0--0--`. Maybe someone familiar with the IB API can tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the order object constructor is setting the `volatility` and `volatilityType` attributes to 0. In this case since the order is not a volatility order (type `VOL`), these attributes should be unset. In the IB API, 'unset' is designated by the maximum value for that primitive data type. So in the Order class,

`volatilityType` would need to be `=` `math.MaxInt32` or `2147483647` and

`volatility` set as `math.MaxFloat64 = 1.7976931348623157e+308`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ib.Order{...}`, try `order := ib.NewOrder()`